# reset applied on chosen() select also resets the placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario in my project to use chosen() select to populate the field with the selected values. Another scenario is to reset the select field which i have implemented as below.

```
$('.chosen-select').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

But the problem is it clears the field values, but once the selected values are cleared the placeholder too goes away. I need the placeholder to be visible as it was before no selection was made.

I have tried a lot of things but still the same issue.

Sample code -> [chosen() select example](https://jsfiddle.net/iamravikk/Legxf0vk/7/)

Sample HTML

```
<select id="second" data-placeholder="Choose a Fruit..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
      <option value=""></option> 
      <option value="Banana">Banana</option> 
      <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option> 
      <option value="Grapes">Grapes</option> 
      <option value="Apple">Apple</option> 
      <option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
      <option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option> 
    </select>
<br /><br />
<p id="status"></p>
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
```

SAMPLE JQUERY

```
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });


$(".chosen-select").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {

  if (params.selected) {

      $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.selected + ' was selected.');
  }
  if (params.deselected) {
     $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.deselected + ' was deselected.');
  }
});
```

Comment: are you using angular ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recreate the chosen:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 var select = $(".chosen-select");
        select.chosen("destroy");
        select.prop("selectedIndex", -1); 
        select.chosen();

        // clear selected text after reset
        $("#status").text('');
});

$(".chosen-select").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {

  if (params.selected) {
      $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.selected + ' was selected.');
  }
  if (params.deselected) {
     $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.deselected + ' was deselected.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select id="second" data-placeholder="Choose a Fruit..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option> 
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option> 
    <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option> 
    <option value="Grapes">Grapes</option> 
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option> 
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
    <option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option> 
</select>
<br /><br />
<p id="status"></p>
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your code.

```
$('button').click(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").val('Choose a Fruit...').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

**Because it's logically setting value for the select-box is ''.** that why you are facing this problem.

Comment: Whatever text you add inside val(), the previous placeholder comes back to whatever it was before.

Currently i put  val('default')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery method chaining, like this- https://jsfiddle.net/iamravikk/Legxf0vk/7/

call .val() before trigger.

```
$(".chosen-select").val('Choose a Fruit...').trigger("chosen:updated");
```